# Why i don't get the same result? Is not the two code denote the same things?

Tags: python, dictionary

Why don't I get the same result? Don't the two codes denote the same things?

Version 1

```
def fun(arg):
    for i in range(0,arg+1):
        return (f'{i}  :  {i**3}')

print(fun(10))
```

Version 2

```
def fun(arg):
    value = {}
    for i in range(0,arg+1):
        value[i] = i ** 3
    return value

print(fun(10))
```

Comment: what do you get from version 1 and version 2? We need to know how they are different in order to answer.

Comment: the simple answer because as soon as your function hits a `return` command, it exits the function. Version 1 tells your function to exit on 1st iteration, while Version 2 tells your function to return after it has collected all values.

Comment: You can see that version 2 returns a dictionary while version 1 has no dictionary at all. How could you expect those codes to deliver the same result?

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet, you return from **inside** the `for` loop, prematurely terminating it and returning a string formatted with i=0.

In the second snippet, you accumulate the results to a dictionary and return the dictionary only after the loop has completed.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not the same thing, in the first code, the value will be returned on the first iteration itself.

While in the second code, all values are aggregated and then, returned.

Answer (score 0):

To know why it doesn't work you need to know the fact that `return` stops `for` loop, or any kind of loop.

So in your first case the return will stop on first iteration which is i = 0 and will return 0: 0.

In your second case, you are storing your values into the variable `value` and by doing that when you return value, you return whole set that for loop went through which is 0 to 10.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that any loop ends when it finds the return keyword, if you want to do the same thing on one line you would have to use dict comprehension:

```
def fun(arg):
    return {i: i**3 for i in range(0, arg+1)}
```